# ADO fails to access oracle in win10

Tags: oracle, internet-explorer-11, ado

My company has long been using ADO to communicate with database, Oracle 10 or 11 typically. This has been working fine in win7 or Windows XP era. But recently some software running on Win10 or Win7 with IE updating from IE8 to IE11 couldn't connect to database with ADO. The code and error is as follow:

```
_ConnectionPtr m_pConnection;
try
{
    hr = m_pConnection->Open(_bstr_t(m_strConnection), _bstr_t(lpstrUserID), _bstr_t(lpstrPassword), NULL);
    return hr == S_OK;
}
catch(_com_error &e)
{

    dump_com_error(e);              
    return FALSE;
}
```

It works fine in win7 but throws exception in win10, the exception object gives information as follow:

```
_com_error &e:
m_hresult = E_FAIL
[0] = 0x536a8590 _com_error::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)
m_perrinfo = 0x013aaaa0
    IUNKOWN
  __vfptr = 0x532d120c
        [0] = 0x533001e0
        [1] = 0x533003c0
        [2] = 0x532fedc0
m_pszMsg = 0x00000000 <Bad Ptr>
```

And the description in the exception object is:

```
   CADODataBase Error
    Code = 80004005
    Code meaning = undefined error
    Source = OraOLEDB
    Description = ORA-12154: TNS: unable to resolve given connection identifier
```

What could lead to this problem and how could I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: It isn't able to locate and/or open your tnsnames.ora file. Make sure your ORACLE_HOME, TNS_ADMIN, and PATH environment variables are set correctly for the session initiating the connection.

Comment: It is same server that is connected by my program on win7 and win10. So I suppose that won't be the cause of the connection error.

Comment: The error is clear: there is something wrong with the environment that your program is running in. It isn't able to resolve a TNS alias because it can't find the tnsnames.ora file, or because you used a bad TNS alias in your connect string.